# store the second string with the first one

Tags: matlab

Write a function called replace that takes three inputs: a cell vector (row or column) of strings and two characters: c1 and c2. The function returns the cell vector unchanged except that each instance of c1 in each string is replaced by c2. You are not allowed to use the built-in function strrep

e.g

```
>> b = replace ({'XOXO' 'XOXO'}, 'X', 'Y')
b = 
    'YOYO'    'YOYO'
```

So far I have come up with the idea

```
function m = replace (A, c1, c2)
[rows,column]=size(A); %size of A
[r,c]=size(A{1}); % size of substring
for i=1:column
    o=A{i};; %Fetching element of string
    for j=1:c
       p= o(j);% fetching string in substring
        if p==c1
            p(j)=c2;% replacing c1 by c2
        else
        p(j)=o(j);% returning as it it
        end
        a(j)=p(j)% storing elements of first string 
          t=a
    end
end
m=t
end
```

In the output I  get YOYO I can't figure out a way to store the second string with the first one.
Please help

Comment: `m` will end up as a cell array of `size(A)`. Index it with `i` like you're indexing `A` for the rest of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly not the most straightforward way, but it can be done in a single line (plus function declaration) using [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) (hover mouse to see):

> `function m = replace(A, c1, c2)`
> `m = cellfun(@(x) char((x==c1).*c2+(x~=c1).*x), A, 'uniformoutput', 0);`

Or as an anonymous function (single line, including everything)

> `replace = @(A,c1,c2) cellfun(@(x) char((x==c1).*c2+(x~=c1).*x), A, 'uniformoutput', 0);`

Comment: @scmg What do you mean? Is there any mistake? Or did you not notice you have to _hover the mouse_ to see it? (I've edited the answer to include that; I thought it was well known)

Comment: oh yeah is that what you did on purpose? :)

Comment: @scmg Yes --- since the question seems to be homework, I prefer to give a hint and not show the answer straight away